# "Friday afternoon" vehicle

Tags: phrases, idioms

New-car buyers often fear that they're getting a "Friday afternoon" vehicle!

What does a "Friday afternoon" vehicle mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's based on the belief that auto workers get lazy at the end of the work week and don't pay much attention to their work. So, they end up making more mistakes and produce a lower quality product.

http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/143350.html

Comment: In the computer industry there is also 'Friday Afternoon Code', but the implication there is that the programmer spent too long in the pub.

Comment: Interestingly a similar idiom in German translates to "a Monday morning vehicle"

Answer (score 3):

A car made on a Friday afternoon when everyone wants to get home early.